# Can't run a standalone QGIS application - ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I'm trying to learn how to create standalone QGIS app. I've gone through a few different errors, now I stuck at:

```
C:\OSGeo4W64>python3 testApp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "testApp.py", line 1, in <module>
    from qgis.core import *
  File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\qgis\__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    from qgis.PyQt import QtCore
  File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\qgis\PyQt\QtCore.py", line 24, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

App is very, very simple because it should only show an empty window:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

window = QtGui.QMainWindow()
window_frame = QtGui.QFrame(window)
window.setCentralWidget(window_frame)
frame_layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(window_frame)

canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
frame_layout.addWidget(canvas)

window.show()
app.exec()
```

Here are environmental variables I use:
(I've tried a lot of different variables giving different errors, this set of variables gives an error written at the top of my post)

```
@echo off
call C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\o4w_env.bat
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W64
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis
set GDAL_DATA=C:\OSGeo4W64\share\gdal\
set PATH=C:\OSGeo4W64\bin;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\bin;%PATH%
SET PYTHONHOME=C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37
set PYTHONPATH=C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python;%PYTHONPATH%

cmd.exe
```

How to fix this problem?

(For a few days I was trying to solve other errors I encountered with this app by searching similar questions on the internet, but I get exhausted by it and finally decided to ask a question here...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the batch file below to set up your environment:

```
@echo off
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W64
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\o4w_env.bat
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\qt5_env.bat
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\py3_env.bat
@echo off
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin
path %PATH%;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Qt5\bin
path %PATH%;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37\Scripts
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT:\=/%/apps/qgis
set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES
rem Set VSI cache to be used as buffer, see #6448
set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python
set PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python37
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\qtplugins;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qt5\plugins

cmd.exe
```

I have tested this with the following minimal standalone script:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFrame, QGridLayout, QMainWindow
from qgis.gui import QgsMapCanvas
from qgis.core import QgsApplication

app = QApplication([])
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)

qgs.setPrefixPath("C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis", True)
qgs.initQgis()

window = QMainWindow()
window_frame = QFrame(window)
window.setCentralWidget(window_frame)
frame_layout = QGridLayout(window_frame)

canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
frame_layout.addWidget(canvas)

window.show()
app.exec()
```

For convenience, you can save both files in the same folder then simply double click on the batch file and, at the command prompt, type: `python testApp.py` and hit enter. You should see the following result with no errors:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I was struggling with setting environmental variables and this python script for a change. One of the answers on the internet said to remove paths to qwindows.dll files, other said it's problem with python path or something like that but I couldn't fix it by myself.
As you can see I'm a newbie in pyqgis, so maybe you could recommend me some resources to learn it, that will give me solid basics? (I'm a little bit sceptical to the book I'm currently getting through on 'Building Mapping Applications with QGIS Erik Westra')

Comment: You're welcome! The book you mention is quite a good resource, but is probably outdated now. It was written for much earlier versions of QGIS 2 and AFAIK has not been updated. There are plenty of free, online resources out there e.g. https://courses.spatialthoughts.com/pyqgis-in-a-day.html  https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/index.html and https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/  I can also recommend this book by the father of QGIS himself Gary Sherman available in hardcopy or pdf: https://locatepress.com/ppg3